# Which thread is responsible for what in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, oop

If i create a two objects that are run to two different threads in Java. If one of the objects calls a method in another object. Is the method run in the thread of the object that calls the method or the object that has the method in it?

Comment: If code on one thread calls a method on an object that is also accessible to another thread, you have to start thinking about thread-safety.

Comment: It is correct to have the view that "objects are state plus behavior" (loosely, an object is data plus the code that operates on it).  When an object is created, though, understand that it is really only the object's state (eg. instance fields, etc.) that is allocated onto the heap.  The object's code base is "shared" by all objects of the class (even non-static code).  And this is exactly what you want, anyway.  Concurrency issues almost always arise from interleaved access of an object's state, and almost never from interleaved access of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method is run in the the thread that calls it.

Classes or objects don't run in threads, but rather code does. So what matters is which thread an object's methods are called.

As Thilo states: classes and objects don't run at all.

Comment: Classes don't run (at all).

Comment: @Thilo: exactly, but that is what the OP is implying should happen.

Answer (score 1):

Unless a thread is explicitly started or the method called runs tasks in another thread (Swing Worker, for instance), it's the same thread.

In any case, the code that starts the new thread runs in the current thread and instructs the JVM to start a thread.

Each thread is an independent line of execution independent of classes or objects(except for when multiple threads try to access the same object; we have locking there), and can access many classes and objects during its lifetime.